# How to remove My Orders From My Dash Board

Tags: magento

Am new in magento

Does anyone know where to remove the `My Orders` link in the navigation on the customer account dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is for a concret link, but if you want remove any link to the customer dashboard you can made a little module to add new action to the block Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation to

The solution here:

Your custom Block in your extension:

```
class CA_Removecustomerlinks_Block_Account_Navigation extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation
{
    /**
     * Removes link by name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links
     * @author @davidselo
     * @company @compraAmiga
     */
    public function removeLinkByName($name)
    {
        foreach ($this->_links as $k => $v) {
            if ($v->getName() == $name) {
                unset($this->_links[$k]);
            }
        }
    
        return $this;
    }
    
}
```

The configuration of your module

## config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CA_Removecustomerlinks>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </CA_Removecustomerlinks>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customer>              
                   <rewrite>
                        <account_navigation>CA_Removecustomerlinks_Block_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
                    </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

and now you can remove as you wish in your local.xml

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>recurring_profiles</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>billing_agreements</name></action>
                <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>downloadable_products</name></action>
        </reference>   
    </customer_account>
```

Comment: The free '[Frontend Links Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/MagePsycho/extension/7905/frontend_links_manager)' extension lets you do this from the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

Got it Guyz

This is Very tricky and hard

Just wanna comment the below code

in **sales.xml**

```
<customer_account>
        <!-- Mage_Sales -->
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
        </reference>

    </customer_account>
```